# Two ChangeNotifierProvider on two different pages

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I provide two `ChangeNotifierProvider` for different pages.

The first page works fine but when I click button and switch to the other side the Provider is not working properly and show me this error:

> *Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this SecondPage Widget*. My code:

**Main**:

```
void main() => runApp(App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => UserListViewModel(),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(
              create: (context) => AnimalViewModel(),
            )
          ],
          child: UserListPage(),
        )
    );
  }
}
```

**UserListPage**:

```
class UserListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserListPageState createState() => _UserListPageState();
}

class _UserListPageState extends State<UserListPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<UserListViewModel>(context, listen: false).fetchUsers("");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final vm = Provider.of<UserListViewModel>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Movies")
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                ),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                  );
                  },
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                          Color(0xFF1976D2),
                          Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child:
                    const Text('Gradient Button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: UserList(users: vm.users))
            ])
        )
    );
  }
}
```

SecondPage:

```
class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final vm = Provider.of<AnimalViewModel>(context);

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Animals")
        ),
        body: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
                ),
                child: RaisedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    vm.setName = 'BumBum';
                  },
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                          Color(0xFF1976D2),
                          Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                    child:
                    const Text('Gradient Button', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                  child: Text(vm.getName))
            ])
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `MultiProvider` above `MaterialApp`. Like this:

```
MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => UserListViewModel(),
    ),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => AnimalViewModel(),
    )
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    home: UserListPage(),
  ),
),
```

The reason you're getting the error is the home widget is a route and that's what  `MultiProvider` wraps. So when you navigate from that route to `SecondPage`, that  route is gone and it can not access `MultiProvider`